# Disable Ping Timeout in IIS Express?

Tags: iis-express

There are a million and one google hits explaining how to disable the ping timeout in IIS (which annoyingly interrupts debugging), which all give this information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763108.aspx

But how do we do this on IIS Express?

(There does not seem to be a configuration interface for IIS Express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS Express does not honor application pool settings except ASP.NET version. So even if you change this setting in config file it won't take effect. That's probably why nobody talks about it.

Meanwhile, if you want a configuration interface similar to IIS Manager, here comes Jexus Manager,

http://jexusmanager.com

Comment: Thanks, but to be clear: the answer is it cannot be done in IIS Express, it we want to suppress the ping timeout we must debug on IIS?

Comment: @Etherman how can you come across ping timeout when using IIS Express? It does not support that feature even.

Comment: If I am debugging and leave the system idle after breaking for a few minutes (e.g. reading spec and checking current values) then I get a new timeout error that invalidates the current debug session, so I have to debug very quickly!

Comment: Maybe this has a different cause, and relates only to partial page updates? I get this timeout error when debugging page from _doPostBack.

Comment: @Etherman it should be another timeout then, which you need to check carefully. There are many timeout values related.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify the applicationHost.config for your instance of IIS Express.

Clicking on the IISExpress Icon will help you find the config file.  For my personal dev/test I use

If you are using the Azure Compute Emulator, the applicationHost.config will change with each local deployment.  For that you will need to modify C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\applicationHost.config.

That file will be copied on each deployment.

Good luck.